# infopath 2010 form in infopath 2013

Tags: infopath, infopath-2007

I have an InfoPath form created in 2003 or 2007, and I am trying to edit this form in InfoPath 2013, the problem is I was not able to view the source code, when I click on rule inspector I can see the programming function written within this form, but with a yellow message "Version Migration Required"

[image]

also when I open Form option I noticed the its written InfoPath 2003 and I am not able to edit the code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You did not really ask a question here.  You really just stated some issues. Assuming your question is how to migrate to a newer version, I suspect you just need to open up your form in design mode and then save as and save your form template into the newer version of InfoPath.

Comment: already my form is saved as 2010 version, and it was opened using design mode, any other suggestion!!

Comment: You might need to open up the source code file in visual studio and target the code to the proper version of the .net framework which is 3.5.  I am not totally sure how to do this off the top of my head but if you are dev savvy you could probably figure it out.